# Adding null to empty TreeSet raising NullPointerException

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, treeset

```
import java.util.TreeSet;
class Test 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        TreeSet t=new TreeSet();
        t.add(null);
        System.out.println(t);
    }
}
```

output: NullPointerException.
I read in many articles that empty TreeSet will accept null for first time but am getting NullPointerException...am using java7..can any body clarify my doubt....

Comment: Why do you want to add `null` to a `TreeSet`? And which articles that might be?

Comment: For me the code works fine on java 1.6. Which java version do you use ?

Comment: I am using java 1.7 version.

Comment: @Eypros in my case it's more that I don't want to have to prune nulls from a collection before converting to a TreeSet.

Answer (score 25):

The [documentation for TreeSet#add](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html#add(E)) in Java 7 states:

> NullPointerException - if the specified element is null and this set uses natural ordering, or its comparator does not permit null elements

So since you have not specified a custom comparator implementation that can handle null values, you get the NPE.

Edit: It was possible to add a `null` element as the first element of a `TreeSet`/`TreeMap` in Java 6, but it was considered a [bug](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=5045147):

Comment: I added first element as null so where is the question of comparing objects? according to my knowledge TreeSet will not compare for first element and It will accept null for first time.

Comment: The documentation is clear, and if you look at the source code of `TreeSet#add` and `TreeMap#put` (which is backing the TreeSet), you'll also see why.

Comment: Thanks for your responce..I understood documentation but feel free to visit this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4uvdetsRq90     see at 15:30 mins he added null and printed value also. can you clarify my doubt

Comment: It says in the comments of that video that it was possible until 1.6, but not from 1.7.

Comment: It says in the compatibility notes from Java 6 to Java 7 that the possibility of adding `null` to a `TreeMap` was a bug: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/compatibility-417013.html#behavioral. See also: http://bugs.sun.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=5045147

Answer (score 5):

This is because for an empty `TreeSet` at the first element a null value can be inserted, but after inserting that first value if we are trying to insert any other objects then we will get a `NullPointerException`.

For a non-empty `TreeSet`, if we are trying to insert a null value at run time you will get a `NullPointerException`. This is because when some elements exist in the tree, before inserting any object it compares the new object to the existing ones using the `compareTo()` method and decides where to put the new object. So by inserting null the `compareTo()` method internally throws  `NullPointerException`.

I think in the new version of Java the null insertion is not allowed.

Answer (score 3):

From 1.7 onwards null is not at all accepted by TreeSet. If you enforce to add then we will get NullPointerException. Till 1.6 null was accepted only as the first element.

Answer (score 2):

API explanation:

Synopsis: Inserting an Invalid Element into a TreeMap Throws an NPE
Description: Due to an error in java.util.TreeMap, it was previously possible to insert invalid null elements and elements not implementing the Comparable interface into an empty TreeMap or TreeSet. Only a single invalid element could be inserted into an empty TreeMap or TreeSet; additional elements would cause the expected NullPointerException or ClassCastException. Most other operations upon the collection would also fail. As of Java SE 7, inserting an invalid null element or an element not implementing Comparable into an empty TreeMap or TreeSet throws a NullPointerException.

Answer (score 0):

TreeSet internally uses Comparable interface to sort the elements in ascending order.
compareTo() method of Comparable interface compare two values each other to find the greater value. When if you add null as element, can not compare null with other value to decide which one is the larger/greater value, for this reason compareTo() method throws NullPointerException.

Declaration of add method in TreeSet is,

`public boolean add(E e) throws ClassCastException, NullPointerException;`

Answer (score 0):

For Empty TreeSet as 1st element null Insertion is possible.
But after inserting that null if we are trying to insert any element we will get NullPointerException.
And for Empty TreeSet if we are trying to Insert null we will get NullPointerException

Answer (score 0):

In Java from Version 1.7 onwards, it is not allowed the first element as null on For Tree set it will give Runtime exception -NullPointerException.
Same if you can try in java 1.6 it will get compiled and run also when adding null on the first element but after that add any element it will give null point exception.

Comment: As far as I can see your answer duplicates other answers. If you think that you can provide better answer then please add extra information and explanation.